# Formatting Phone Numbers in R

Tags: r, if-statement, gsub

So I have a list of phone numbers that don't have standard formatting, thus they can be (123)-456-7890, 1234567890, 456890, 456-7890.

I want to go through my list of phone numbers and format them to be
123-456-7890
456-7890

So far what I have in R is

```
 phone_num <- gsub("-","", gsub("\\(","", gsub("\\)","", csv_file$Phone)))

 if(nchar(phone_num)== 10) {
    cleaned_phone <-gsub("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", phone_num) 
  }
    else if (nchar(phone_num) == 7){
             cleaned_phone <-gsub("(\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "\\1-\\2", phone_num)
    }
         else (nchar(phone_num) != 7 || nchar(phone_num) != 10){
              cleaned_phone <- #delete entry
         }
```

But I am getting errors - any ideas?

I'm looking to have the output be for phone numbers of length 10 to be formatted as 123-456-7890, for phone numbers of length 7, be formatted as 123-4567. for non valid entries, those should be deleted.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: In your last `else` I think you want an `&&` instead of a `||`. As it stands it will always be true.  Also you want an `if` there, or alternatively just remove the condition.

Comment: @JohnPaul `else` shouldn't be given arguments in the first place

Comment: I think it was supposed to be another `else if` but the `if` part was accidentally omitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on Eric's answer and trying to put all the pieces together, I think this is how I would go about it.

The key steps are to

1. Remove all the punctuation.  At this point, everything should be numeric or character values.
2. Set all phone numbers that are not 7 or 10 digits to NA (or some other value of your choosing)
3. reformat 7 digit numbers
4. reformat 10 digit numbers.

I've tried a few different approaches, but this one seems to be the most efficient.

```
phone_it_in <- function(phone, invalid = NA)
{
  phone <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", phone)          # remove punctuation
  phone <- trimws(phone)                           # remove whitespace
  phone[!nchar(phone) %in% c(7, 10)] <- invalid    # keep only 7 or 10 digit numbers
  phone[nchar(phone) %in% 7] <- gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", 
                                   "\\1-\\2", 
                                   phone[nchar(phone) %in% 7])
  phone[nchar(phone) %in% 10] <- gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", 
                                    "\\1-\\2-\\3",
                                    phone[nchar(phone) %in% 10])
  phone
}

phone <- c("(123)-456-7890", "1234567890", "456890", "456-7890")
phone_it_in(phone)
```

EDIT: Changed from `invalid = NA` because it resulted in the following error:

```
Error in phone[nchar(phone) == 7] <- gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "\\1-\\2", : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
Traceback:
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this,

```
p <- c("(123)-456-7890", "1234567890", "456890  ", "456-7890", "   (123)-4567890")
p
# >[1] "(123)-456-7890"   "1234567890"       "456890  "         "456-7890"        
# >[5] "   (123)-4567890"
p <- trimws(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", p))
# > # p <- gsub("[-,),(]", "", p) ) # altrenative, but does not remove whitespace!
p
# >[1] "1234567890" "1234567890" "456890"     "4567890"    "1234567890"
p[!nchar(p) %in% c(10)] <- NA
p
# >[1] "1234567890" "1234567890" NA           NA           "1234567890"
p <- gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", p)
p
# >[1] "123-456-7890" "123-456-7890" NA             NA             "123-456-7890"
p <- p[!is.na(p)] # to remove NA's
p
# >[1] "123-456-7890" "123-456-7890" "123-456-7890"
```

Comment: You could streamline the cleaning step with `trimws(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", phone))` (eliminate whitespace as well) and then change your last line to `ifelse(nchar(phone) == 7, gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "\\1-\\2", phone), gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", phone))` and you'll get the right format for the seven digit number.  A decision still needs to be made about what to do with any other string length (such as `phone[!nchar(phone) %in% c(7, 10)] <- NA`)

Comment: I was just about to edit my question - if they are less than 7 digits (i.e a valid phone number) I would like to delete that entry